# Retagging Question : Sets of tags with redundant meaning

Tags: discussion, questions, tags

Sometimes I see a question where the tags are like:

`asp.net asp.net-ajax .NET ajax`

That is, some of the tags in the set are redundant to the tag-set's meaning (which could be simplified to `asp.net-ajax` or `asp.net ajax`).

What is the proper retagging ettiquite in these cases - if any retagging at all?

Comment: That's a tough one, sometime five tags really isn't enough.

Comment: My only thought is that if you are asking a question about Visual Studio, but it could apply to any version, don't use the tag "visual-studio-2010" or similar. Some tags are more specific than the question requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That actually looks reasonable to me.

- `asp.net` generally implies ASP.NET WebForms (otherwise it would be tagged `asp.net-mvc`)
- `asp.net-ajax` refers to the Microsoft ASP.NET Ajax library, which applies to both WebForms and MVC
- `ajax` is a general tag that might imply that the issue is not entirely specific to the ASP.NET Ajax library - maybe it's a general Ajax question and the question author simply happens to be using the MS Ajax library
- `.net` should definitely be there - even though `asp.net` implies `.net`, it helps a lot with tag searches, favourite tags, etc. to have that top level tag.  Most .NET questions tend to be tagged with either `.net`, `c#`, or `vb.net`.  As above, the `.net` tag may imply that the asker happens to be using ASP.NET but that the question may really be more generally about .NET.

So I would say leave it the way it is.

Comment: You'd have to be pretty stupid to think that those four tags mean the same thing.

Comment: The tags themselves are different - but put together they mean the same thing. For example, : `asp.net asp.net-ajax .NET ajax` as a set of tags, has the same meaning as the set: `asp.net AJAX`. That's what I'm asking.

Comment: More tags mean more coverage for people favouriting tags. It's better to have more than fewer, as long as the tags are individually valid.

Comment: Wel'Bog, I'd accept your answer if it was one.

Comment: @rlb.usa: Actually, `asp.net` and `ajax` would not be the same as `asp.net-ajax`. ASP.NET Ajax is a single library and there are other ways to create Ajax requests in ASP.NET (jQuery, for instance - a question tagged `asp.net` + `ajax` + `jquery` would make perfect sense).